# RoR routing very basic problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, url-routing

I have Exam controller.

In routes.rb there is "resources :exams"

In controller there are REST-like generated methods.

I want to add my own method there:

```
def search
  @exams = Exam.where("name like ?", params[:q])
end
```

In view file:

```
<%= form_tag(search_path, :method => "post") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Szukaj: ") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Szukaj") %>
<% end %>
```

I know, there is no results presentation yet, it doesn't work at all at this moment (:

When i go to http://localhost:3000/exams/search it's mapping it to show controller and search is a :id paramether then...

How to get http://localhost:3000/exams/search to run the seach controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add route. Put this in `routes.rb`, before `resources :exams`

```
map.search '/exams/search', :controller => :exams, :action => :search
```

Note, that `resources :exams` doesn't generate routes for all public methods of the controller, it generates very specific set of routes. You can find more information in the [rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). (see section 3.2 in particular)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add additional parameters to your mapping. You can add "collection" methods like so:

```
map.resources :exams, :collection => {:search => :get}
```

When you `rake routes`, you'll see that it generates something like so:

```
search_exams GET    /exams/search(.:format)    {:controller=>"exams", :action=>"search"}
       exams GET    /exams(.:format)           {:controller=>"exams", :action=>"index"}
             POST   /exams(.:format)           {:controller=>"exams", :action=>"create"}
    new_exam GET    /exams/new(.:format)       {:controller=>"exams", :action=>"new"}
   edit_exam GET    /exams/:id/edit(.:format)  {:controller=>"exams", :action=>"edit"}
        exam GET    /exams/:id(.:format)       {:controller=>"exams", :action=>"show"}
             PUT    /exams/:id(.:format)       {:controller=>"exams", :action=>"update"}
             DELETE /exams/:id(.:format)       {:controller=>"exams", :action=>"destroy"}
```